# Horizontal ruler on the component list

Tags: inno-setup

How to create such horizontal ruler on the component list:

[image: example]

I've tried different solutions like:

```
[Components]
Name: "div"; Description: "-----------------------------------------------";
```

But it's always showing a checkbox

Comment: Where is the screenshot from? Is it really components page of some existing Inno Setup installer? Which one?

Comment: from [this installer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4SoKiBdCMJbQWc2ajVrZUVCMEE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I cannot try it, as I do not have World of Tanks (and mod pack does not even start without it) - Though there are no components in that installer, and the installer calls `AddGroup` method, so it clearly does something like the duplicate question above.